# True Polymorph question

Tags: spells

One of my players asked if they could change their characters creature type using True Polymorph without changing their character to much. They play a tabaxi and they want to add or change thier type to fiend. I read the spell but it doesn't cover this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What game is this question about?

Comment: You should [edit] in the relevant tag for the system (and edition) you are playing. Eg. [dnd-5e].

Comment: Also, whatever system it is, it may be worth rereading the spell description; if it answers your question, then once you tag the question with the right system and it is reopened, you can even add a self-answer to the question!